# Improve performance for huge ListBox in StackPanel?

Tags: wpf, listbox, virtualizingstackpanel, ui-virtualization

I am using a StackPanel to layout several controls vertically (ie, Title, sub titles, listbox, separator, listbox, etc).

The StackPanel is a child of a ScrollViewer to ensure its content is always scrollable.

One of the controls in the StackPanel is a ListBox.

Its ItemsSource is data bound to a huge collection, and a complex DataTemplate is used to realise each item.

Unfortunately, I'm getting really poor performance (high cpu/memory) with it.

I tried

- setting the ListBox's ItemsPanel to a VirtualizingStackPanel, and
- overriding its ControlTemplate to only an ItemsPresenter (remove the ListBox's ScrollViewer).

But there were no difference in performances. I'm guessing the StackPanel gives its internal children infinite height during measure?

When I replaced the ScrollViewer and StackPanel with other panels/layouts (e.g, Grid, DockPanel) and the performance improves significantly, which leads me to believe the bottleneck, as well as solution, is in virtualization.

Is there any way for me to improve the cpu/memory performance of this view?

[image]

**[Update 1]**

Original Sample project: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=29810707815310047536

**[Update 2]**

I tried restyling/templating TreeView/TreeViewItems to come up with the following example. It still takes a long time to start/same,high memory usage. But once loaded, scrolling feels a lot more responsive than the original sample.

Wonder if there's any other way to further improve the start up time/memory usage?

Restyled TreeView project: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00117351345725628185

**[Update 2]**

pushpraj's solution works like a charm

- Original:

  - Startup: 35s,
  - Memory: 393MB
  - Scrolling: Slow
- TreeView:

  - Startup: 18s,
  - Memory 377MB,
  - Scrolling: Fast
- pushpraj's solution:

  - Startup: <1s,
  - Memory: 20MB,
  - Scrolling: Fast

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you may perhaps limit the maximum size of the huge list box and enable `Virtualization`

eg

```
<ListBox MaxHeight="500" 
         VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="true" 
         VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" />
```

this will enable the ListBox to load a few items only and will enable a scrollbar on listbox to scroll to rest of the items if needed.

at the same time setting `VirtualizationMode` to `Recycling` will help you to reuse the complex data templates thus eliminating the need of re creating them again for every item.

---

**EDIT**

here is a solution based on your sample, I have used `CompositeCollection` with `Virtualization` to achieve the desired.

xaml

```
<Grid xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
      xmlns:l="clr-namespace:PerfTest">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:Permission}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <Button Content="+" />
                <Button Content="-" />
                <Button Content="..." />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <CompositeCollection x:Key="data">
            <!-- Content 1 -->
            <TextBlock Text="Title"
                       FontSize="24"
                       FontWeight="Thin" />
            <!-- Content 2 -->
            <TextBlock Text="Subtitle"
                       FontSize="16"
                       FontWeight="Thin" />
            <!-- Content 3 -->
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding DataContext, Source={x:Reference listbox}}" />
            <!-- Content 4 -->
            <TextBlock Text="User must scroll past the entire list box before seeing this"
                       FontSize="16"
                       FontWeight="Thin"
                       Padding="5"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Background="#99000000"
                       Foreground="White" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox"
             VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
             VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             ItemsSource="{StaticResource data}" />
</Grid>
```

code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var items = new ObservableCollection<Permission>();
        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).Select(i => new Permission() { Name = "Permission " + i }))
        { items.Add(i); }
        DataContext = items;
    }
}

public class Permission
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

since we can not create data template for string so I changed the string collection to `Permission` collection. I hope in your real project it would be something similar.

give this a try and see if this is close to what you need.

note: you may safely ignore if there is any designer warning on `Collection="{Binding DataContext, Source={x:Reference listbox}}"`

Comment: Fixing the listbox's max height would cause 2 scrollbars to appear (see http://i.imgur.com/s1MJ6BO.png?1)

Comment: that is true, but at the same time virtualization can only work when the height is fixed or max height is defined, it can not work for unlimited height. You may perhaps make use of composite collection combine all of the items in the stackpanel and display all of them in a listbox with Virtualization enabled. may you share the code, I'll try to help you with that.

Comment: Updated to include sample project

Comment: @jsjslim I updated my answer to match your needs. now it loads quite fast with no extra scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks! Very fast start up, low memory usage. I definitely need to start exploring the other classes that comes with .NET/WPF.